# oidc-client authentication failure: sub from user info endpoint does not match sub in access_token

Tags: oidc-client-js

I have an angular app using oidc-client to access an API that uses IdentityServer3 to provide OpenID Connect authentication.

During authentication the oidc-client throws an error:

```
sub from user info endpoint does not match sub in access_token
```

FYI the following steps were successful:

- POST to the API's `/openid/login?signin=xxx`
- redirect to the API's `/openid/connect/authorize`
- redirect back to the angular app

But then oidc-client made a call to the API's `/openid/connect/userinfo`.

The API does not implement the userinfo endpoint, the `/openid/connect/userinfo` returns an empty object: `{}`.

And then oidc-client stopped the whole thing with the above error message.

Is there an option in oidc-client to skip that call to the userinfo endpoint? Or is it mandatory for the API to implement that endpoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

oidc will always call the userinfo internally to **verify** user as by default it is set to  **true** and its incoming access_token by querying the .well-known/openid-configuration.
It is also not good idea to skip this. Is your client application registered properly on IDP.

Look at the below oidc-client option configuration which controls the userinfo endpoint:

[oidc-client-js](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/wiki)

- **loadUserInfo** (boolean, default: true): Flag to control if additional identity data is loaded from the user info endpoint in order to populate the user's profile.

Comment: Thanks! With `loadUserInfo` set to false oidc-client didn't send the userinfo request. It skipped to the next step, sending `/openid/connect/checksession` request.